# Why std::string concatenation in one expression gives different result than char by char?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm concatenating 3 chars from the middle of a std::string. If I do it char by char, I get the expected result, but if I do it in only one expression, I get a weird result. Why?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1 = "abcdefghijklmnopq";
    string s2 = "";
    string s3 = "";

    s3+=s1[4];
    s3+=s1[5];
    s3+=s1[6];
    cout << s3 << endl;  // Expected behaviour

    s2=s1[4]+s1[5]+s1[6];
    cout << s2 << endl;  // ?????
}
```

Comment: You are adding `char`s  **not** `std::string`s

Comment: You've gotten answers explaining why; one solution is to force the right-hand side to become `std::string`, which you can do with a conversion: `s3 += std::string(s1[4]) + s1[5] + s1[6];`. This relies on the rule that `+` groups left to right, as if the expression on the right had been written `(std::string(s1[4]) + s1[5]) + s1[6]`. If you're uncomfortable with that, you can write it in a somewhat strange-looking form that does not rely on grouping: `s1[4] + std::string(s1[5]) + s1[6]`.

Answer (score 8):

`s1[4]+s1[5]+s1[6]` uses the built-in `+` on a `char` type: every argument is promoted to an `int` and the expression is an `int` type. When this is assigned to `s2`, the overloaded `=` operator to `char` is called, and the expression is truncated to a `char` prior to the assignment. If `char` is `signed` on your platform, then this is *implementation defined*. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion.

`s3+=s1[4];` and company uses the overloaded `+=` operator on the `std::string` for a `char` argument. That is defined to *concatenate* the `char` to the string.

Finally from C++14 onwards, you *could* use the beautiful

```
s2 = ""s + s1[4] + s1[5] + s1[6];
```

if `substr` cannot come to your rescue (`s2 = s1.substr(4, 3);` would do the job in this particular case). Note the *user defined literal* `""s` defined in the C++14 Standard Library.

Comment: The OP *probably* wants to use `s2 = s1.substr(4, 3);`

Comment: C++ is counterintuitive again , the sum of to chars, is not a char. In that case there should be a concatenation operator just to make it clear that you are not adding values, but concatenating them. Even more obscure is the fact that it allows assigning an integer to a string.

Comment: @ManuelPastor: Actually, the `int` is converted to a `char`, and the overloaded `=` to a `char` is called. I've put some more beef in the answer.